# Drupal failed after update

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I just updated Drupal core from 7.4 to 7.26. After running update.php site stopped working – both *public* and *admin* part. When I load it fatal error occurs:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function _system_default_theme_features() in /[drupal_path]/includes/theme.inc on line 1422

and when I reload it another fatal error apperars:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getDirectoryPath() on a non-object in /[drupal_path]/modules/image/image.module on line 83

next reload – first error, one more – second. Also, second error is loading much faster.

And one more thing, after applaying update.php I got one *failed*, I don't know if this is connected:

> media_gallery module
>
> Update #7009
>
> Failed: FieldException: Próba aktualizacji egzemplarza nieistniejącego pola media_gallery_media. w field_update_instance() (linia 557 z /[drupal_path]/modules/field/field.crud.inc).

which is something like:

> Failed: FieldException: Attempt to update an instance of a nonexistent field media_gallery_media. in field_update_instance() (line 557 in /[drupal_path]/modules/field/field.crud.inc).
> PHP Version 5.5.6

Any tips where the problem is? I was trying disabling some modules from db, but this did't help.

Comment: Few checks: Did you use the latest .htaccess file? Of course, you are very late in upgrading your site -- you were using 7.04 till now! Disable those modules with errors by navigating to db > system table and try again.

Comment: Yes, .htaccess was updated as everything else. And I disabled image.module from db – didn't help :(

Comment: and media_gallery (mentioned in update.php) already was disabled.

Comment: Are you able to roll back to 7.04? Have you tried disabling all non core modules? Did you backup the database before updating? Were all modules, themes up to date or did you plan to update after core ...?

Comment: Now, flush cache_bootstrap & cache tables in db and check.

Comment: thank You for comments. Somehow (I have no idea how) system.module has status=0 in db. When I set it to 1 it started to work. Suggestion from drupal.stackexchange helped me a lot in figuring it out.

Comment: And responses:

Probably I was able to rollback. I've tried disabling non-core modules, but not all, some. Yes, I did backup. Non-core updates were done before.

Caches were flushed.

Thx once more.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to explain the reason and to provide a solution.
My attempt would be to copy the DB and the files on a neutral platform (local machine or so) and experiment with the update.php script.

My suspicion would be that media module needs also update since it's using the old URI function definition (call). Also try to update other modules that are working with files.
The update is quite big since 7.4 to 7.22 (years of improvement). Reading the change log would be helpful but not realistic.

Did you also cleared the cache? (via drush if the web interface not working - /?q=admin/config/development/performance)

Please don't forget to post the solution if you find one for other users with the same issue.

Comment: Thank You. As I mentioned above core module was disabled in db (it had status=0). When I set it to 1 it started to work. Suggestion from drupal.stackexchange helped me a lot in figuring it out. I have no idea what had disabled core module...